# Node.js foreach + promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I want to print `arr=[1, 2, 3, 4]` like below.

1
101
2
102
3
103
4
104

but result is below.

1
2
3
4
101
102
103
104

my code

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];


var promises = [];
arr.forEach(function(elem){
    print(elem)
        .then(addAndPrint)
}
)

function print(elem){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        console.log(elem);
        resolve(elem);
    });
}
function addAndPrint(elem){
    console.log(elem + 100);
}
```

How can I get result I want?

Comment: you need each iteration to wait for the previous one to finish to get tht output ... so, use promise chaining - e.g. `let promise = Promise.resolve();

arr.forEach(function(elem){
    promise = promise.then(() => printt(elem).then(addAndPrint));
});`

Comment: Why do u wnat promises here. You can do it in totally snchronous way

Comment: This is my sample code. Actually, I should use request in addAndPrint part. So, I want to use promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.then`s execute *asynchronously* (similar to `setTimeout(.., 0)`) (even if the promise resolves immediately), whereas the promise creation function in `new Promise((res, rej) => {` runs synchronously. So, if you create a bunch of promises *synchronously*, such as with `forEach` before the main thread ends, those promises' blocks will all run immediately *before* any of the `then`s are reached.

Use `await` and either `reduce` or `for..of` to ensure the iterations run *in serial*, not in parallel:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];


var promises = [];
arr.reduce(async function(lastPromise, elem) {
  await lastPromise;
  return print(elem)
    .then(addAndPrint)
}, Promise.resolve())

function print(elem) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log(elem);
    resolve(elem);
  });
}

function addAndPrint(elem) {
  console.log(elem + 100);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what constraints you're working with but the choice to use Promises could use some explanation. Because the easiest solution is probably to not use Promises. Promises are good for asynchronous operations, but everything here is synchronous.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

arr.forEach(function(elem){
  print(elem)
  addAndPrint(elem);
});

function print(elem){
  console.log(elem);
}
function addAndPrint(elem){
  console.log(elem + 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.then` can only guarantee your `addAndPrint(1)` method is executed after `print(1)` method, but can't make `print(2)` after `addAndPrint(1)`.